# Make EditText accept non-English numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers, multilingual

I made a very simple app that involves only numbers and there is no need to make different locale folders or anything.

When I test the app, the `EditText` will take numbers when the keyboard language is English, but when I change the keyboard to other languages it does not work! pressing a number will not show up in the `EditText`.

Is there a way to make the `EditText` take universal numbers regardless of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work

```
 <EditText 
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal|numberPassword|number"/>
```

and according your need put separator between choice i.e `|` and press **ctrl+space** you will get more option .

Comment: It worked! (I took the "numberPassword" part to keep numbers visible though). Thank you Cobra Ajgar.

Answer (score 0):

you'd add   android:inputType="number"

Comment: I did, the inputType is numberDecimal. It is accepting numbers, but only when the language of the keyboard is English!