# Show only English characters when editing text in EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 3 languages on my keyboard in android device and I want to show only English language letters and numbers when starting to edit text inside EditText like username field , I tried to use this line in xml file for Edittext but without any result.

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
```

Comment: I think you should change the title of your question. I got the impression that you are asking how to prevent the user from using a non-english **keyboard**. Which is probably not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324248/how-to-force-english-keyboard-in-android-edittext?rq=1

Comment: Somewhat related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578009/my-edittext-will-accept-numbers-only-in-english-is-there-a-way-to-change-that-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is to use `inputfilter` and set it to your `editText` you can see a workaround to do that here :

[How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

also i found a code snippet to this like below:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (!isEnglishOrHebrew(source.charAt(i))) { 
            return "";
        }
    }
    return null; 
}

private boolean isEnglishOrHebrew(char c) {
    . . .
}
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```